# Comparing two arrays in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to do **Reverse Intersection** operation with two arrays and save the result in a different array

Eg: Array A {1, 2, 3}; Array B {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} Resultant Array Should be {4, 5, 6}

I Tried out the following logic but didn't work

```
int k = 0;
int a[2] = {1,10};
int p[10];
int roll[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == roll[j])
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            p[k] = 0;
            p[k] = roll[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

I need it for my vb.net project

Comment: Well, there's your problem right there; that's not VB.NET.

Comment: I just tried out the logic in C++ in a local system.. No vb.net available right now. Just the logic will help

Comment: If you're allowed to use the System.Linq namespace in your (I assume) homework, it makes this a whole lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. And to clarify, it's not Homework

Comment: My mistake then. Tim Schmelter's answer uses System.Linq.Enumerable, which is your best bet at this point unless you specifically want to learn the algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't understand how that C# code is related to your VB.NET problem, if you only want to find `integers` which are in one array and not in the other, use `Enumerable.Except`:

```
Dim intsA = {1, 2, 3}
Dim intsB = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Dim bOnly = intsB.Except(intsA).ToArray()
```

Comment: how can I store the result in an integer array

Comment: when i try to display the content as MsgBox(bOnly(0)) it's displaying 0 not 4

Comment: @Dineshbabu: `MsgBox(bOnly(0))` opens a message-box with `4` for me.

Comment: I will post another question then

Comment: I posted the question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790580/reverse-intersection-operation-with-arrays-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you can't use Linq:

```
Function RevIntersect(arr1() As String, arr2() As String) As String()
    Dim sResult, aux As New List(Of String)()

    aux.AddRange(arr1)
    aux.AddRange(arr2)

    For Each elem As String In aux
        If (Not arr1.Contains(elem) OrElse Not Arr2.Contains(elem)) AndAlso _
        Not sResult.Contains(elem) Then  
            sResult.Add(elem)
        End If
    Next

    Return sResult.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: That's intersect. They want reverse intersect, i.e. except. =)