# Reverse Intersection operation with arrays vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim count as Short = 10
    Dim roll(count), absent(count), present(count) As Short
    Dim i As Short = 1
    query = "SELECT * FROM primary_student_table WHERE admityear=" & year & " AND batch= " & batch & ""
    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
    re = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While re.Read
            roll(i) = re("roll")
            i += 1
    End While
    con.Close()

    absent = txtlist.Text.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Short.Parse(s)).ToArray()
    present = roll.Except(absent).ToArray()
        MsgBox(absent(0))
        MsgBox(present(0))
```

In the above code, the values in the arrays are as follows

- **roll=21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30  (rollNos of all the students
  in the class)**
- txtlist.text value = 21,22 (meaning those two were absent for the class)

Now I need to **save the absentees rolls in the array absent and the rest of the rolls in array present**

The absentees list gets saved correctly but the second MsgBox is displaying 0 instead of 23

What's wrong with the code

Comment: Is `roll` really what you think it is? What does this return: `String.Join(",",roll)`? You should start using `List(Of T)` instead of arrays when you don't know the size or if you have to add/remove items from the collection.

Comment: It just contain numbers

Comment: `Dim roll As New List(Of Short)     While re.Read     roll.Add(re("roll"))       i += 1   End While` Is this right?   @TimSchmelter

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you comment on my last comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in VB.NET are zero-based. You are setting values in roll starting from index 1 :

```
Dim i As Short = 1
```

Then when you're reading the datareader, you're loading into roll array starting from index 1.

```
'i is set to 1, so you're setting values from the second array item onwards
While re.Read
        roll(i) = re("roll")
        i += 1
End While
```

So the value of roll(0) is always 0, and this will be sent to your present array.

The reason that you're probably not getting an index out of bounds exception when reading from your datareader is because your datareader returns 10 rows, and your roll array can hold 11 (roll(10) is actually an array of 11).

Set the value of i to 0, and it should be fine:

```
Dim i As Short = 0
```

**EDIT:**
As per Tim Schmelter's advice, you really should consider using List(Of T) instead of arrays. Also, consider using parameterized sql queries.

Comment: You might want to suggest to use a `List(Of T)` instead ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Short = 1
```

Should have been

```
Dim i As Short = 0
```

This solved the problem